# Texmaker editor and others show incorrect cyrillic symbols

Tags: texmaker, font-encodings

I'm trying to build a template from this [russian journal](http://pleiades.online/ru/authors/guidlines/prepare-electonic-version/tex-latex/). But no editor can recognize what encoding is used. It is supposed to be 'cp866' but it looks like this

```
ВЏГ В®Г¦ВҐГЎГЎ В®Г¤В®Г В¬В«ВҐВ­ВЁВЁ ГЎГўВ ГўГ¬ВЁ ГЎ ВЇВ®В¬В®Г©Г¬Г® REV\TeX~4
```

instead of

```
Процесс оформления статьи с помощью REV\TeX~4
```

The other examples of a text that are shown incorrectly are [here](http://pleiades.online/pub/tex/maik/maik02.txt) and [there](http://www.maik.ru/pub/tex/maik/). 
Is there a problem with my OS?

Comment: Opening with IBM866 it looks reasonable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

It appears to be IBM866 format

Comment: I've tried it just gives the different set of incorrect characters, for instance, for the 1st author  `\author{\firstname{┬П.~A.}~\surname{┬П┬е├ ┬в├л┬й-тВм┬в├в┬о├ }}
% тАб┬д┬е├б├м ├ ┬ ┬з┬б┬и┬е┬н┬и┬е ┬н┬  ├б├в├ ┬о┬к┬и ┬о├б├г├й┬е├б├в┬в┬л├п┬е├в├б├п ┬ ┬в├в┬о┬м┬ ├в┬и├з┬е├б┬к┬и ┬и┬л┬и ┬к┬о┬м┬ ┬н┬д┬о┬й \\`.

Comment: Notepad++ shows the same strings ` \author{\firstname{┬П.~A.}~\surname{┬П┬е├ ┬в├л┬й-тВм┬в├в┬о├ }}
% тАб┬д┬е├б├м ├ ┬ ┬з┬б┬и┬е┬н┬и┬е ┬н┬  ├б├в├ ┬о┬к┬и ┬о├б├г├й┬е├б├в┬в┬л├п┬е├в├б├п ┬ ┬в├в┬о┬м┬ ├в┬и├з┬е├б┬к┬и ┬и┬л┬и ┬к┬о┬м┬ ┬н┬д┬о┬й \\ ` when I choose OEM 866

Comment: I've just reloaded the tex file from the site and done what you said, now everything is fine. Thanks